# Constraint for state values in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have a state key named `zoom` than can have values between 0 and 100. Is there a way I can make constraint for these values?

For know I make a new method (but it looks overengineering):

```

```
<Component onChange={this.handleOnchange}/>

handleOnChnage(value){
//instead of this.setState({zoom:value});
this.setZoomState(value);//where I check the value and make the constaints
}
```

is there any more elegant solution to apply constraints to the state keys?

Comment: If you think you have to do that, then that would be the way.

Comment: You always need to set the constraints somewhere, and apply the validation to your input value somewhere. The "best place to do that" or "more elegant solution" depends on context: in which and how many places do you need to do the same validation? are the boundaries 0 and 100 global contstants or user/ platform dependent? in how many places do you update your state where validation needs to be applied?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it depends on complexity of constraint.

If the constraint is really simple, you could do it inline, like this:

```
this.setState ( { zoom : min(100, max(value, 0)) } );
```

Somewhat more readable is this:

```
var validatedZoom = min(100, max(value, 0));
this.setState( { zoom : validatedZoom } );
```

If validation is more complex (e.g. generates message for user) or if validation needs to be reusable, a separate validation function is probably best way to go. In the simple example:

```
function validatedZoom(value) {
  return min(100, max(value, 0));
}
// elsewhere
this.setState( { zoom : validatedZoom(value) } );
```

Or the answer provided by @janakastevens

Comment: That means you have to do `var validatedZoom = min(100, max(value, 0));` every where you set the zoom. Repeating the bussins logic is not a wise step

Comment: Depends on your setup/ readability requirement I guess. The examples in the answer are in line with the (limited) complexity of the question. "Repeating business" logic would apply e.g. if you do setState in multiple places. In that case -> seperate validation function. Complex validation? -> separate validation function. I updated my answer just to be sure..

Answer (score 0):

It could look like this.

```js
handleOnChange(event){
  var newValue = this.checkZoomValue(event.target.value);
  this.setState({zoom:newValue});
}
checkZoomValue(value) {
  var outValue = min(value, 100)
  outValue = max(value, 0);
  return outValue;
}
```

Comment: still need to be aware of the constraint each time I use setState :(